# how do I restore the path in ubuntu(for installing elixir)

Tags: ubuntu, path

I first used asdf to install elixir, but there was an error and it was hard to fix it

so I just uninstalled elixir and asdf. After removing all the things(asdf) I downloaded elixir by sudo apt-get install elixir and when I typed elixir --version I got this message

[image]

How do I change the directory?
The paths are like this(Using echo $Path)

[image]

Is there a way to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the ~/.bashrc file to see if the path is set there. By the way, I'm going to remove the Elixir tag from this question as this is nothing specific to Elixir.